Another primality test
Perhaps all the primality tests I've seen are based on Fermat's little theorem, which states that if $p$ is a prime number, for base 2, the following congruence holds.
\begin{align}
 2^p \equiv 2 \pmod{p}
\end{align}
While I was playing around with numbers, I discovered another similar primality test.
My primality test still states that if $p$ is a prime number, then the following congruences hold.
\begin{align}
 2^p - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}
\end{align}
Rewritting $2^p - 2$ as a sum gives
\begin{align}
 \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} 2^i \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \text{.}
\end{align}
Or for other bases:
\begin{align}
 \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} b 2^i \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \text{,}
\end{align}
where $b>0$.
And now, it is easy to replace $2^i$ with sequence of summation (here in the C language):
int test(unsigned long base, unsigned long p)
{
    unsigned long result = 0;

    for (unsigned long i = 1; i < p; ++i) {
        base += base;
        base %= p;

        result += base;
        result %= p;
    }

    return result == 0;
}

So finally we have $2p-2$ summations instead of $p$ multiplications.
All numbers (base, result) are in modulo $p$.
This is still base-2 Fermat test with all its pseudoprimes.
I know that $p$ multiplications can be computed quickly using modular exponentiation, but I tried using this algorithm, and it is not faster than a sequence of additions (at least for small numbers).
I verified my algorithm on numbers up to 100,000.
Can you confirm my result?
Is it possible to use my test for something useful?
Can the summation sequence be speeded up even further?
All feedback is welcome.

Does your question ask what is faster for computer: multiplication or addition?

@user Maybe. I'm wondering if there is an application where my test is actually faster than the original Fermat's test.

Calculating $2^p$ does not take about $p$ multiplications but only about $\lg{p}$. See Exponentiation by squaring. Your method still takes $p$ steps instead of $\lg{p}$.

Your starting point is trivial because $n^p-n\equiv0\mod p$ for all integer positive $n\lt p$ .Will see what follow. A prime test is very interesting and useful if new and easy to apply.

@JaapScherphuis You are right. My algorithm has a worse complexity in terms of Big-O.

You algorithm just calculates $b(2^p-2) \bmod p$  in a very inefficient way.
